# Count the area of rasterdata in specific shapefile polygons (residential density in different districts)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, shapefile, area, density

I'd like to count the exact area of three different residential classes (low, medium, high) by district of a shapefile which contains 225 districts. like: district 1 has: XXX sqm low, XXX sqm medium, XXX sqm high. distict 2 has: XXX....

the residential classes are a file system raster, the districs are one shapefile.

I can count the total area of the residential classes of the whole study area. but I can't count the area for every unique district I have in the shapefile. (Maybe I could count the area for 1-3 specific districts I pick but for 225 it would be too time-consuming) After all I'd like to see the area of each district in the attribute table of the district-shapefile and be able to export the data to Excel. I hope you can help, thanks.

Comment: What GIS software and version are you using?

Comment: Arcgis 10 Service Pack 3

Comment: Do you have access to Spatial Analyst?

Comment: Yes I have access to many toolboxes, including Spatial Analyst Tools

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have access to Spatial Analyst extension. Tabulate Area should do the trick, but you do need to be mindful of overlapping zones (e.g. districts).

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w2000000

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Tabulate Area** tool to do the job.
Use the following steps to get the values for all 255 districts (or any number you might have):

**1)** If your district polygon shape file does not have a unique Identifier for each feature in the attribute table, then add it, i.e. add a new field named Id (or any other name) and calculate Id = FID + 1. The unique field will be needed later on in step 3.

**2)** Run the **Tabulate Area** (Spatial Analyst) and use your district polygon as "Input raster or feature zone data". The tool will create a table with the areas of each classes that fall into each district and load it to ArcMap.

**3)** Then right click on your district shape file and select **Joins and Relates** and "Join attributes from a table", choose an Id field added in point 1, then select the table created in 2 and then a Rowid or ID - this will add the results obtained in point 2 to the district shape file - JOB DONE! To make the Join permanent **export the district shapefile** to a new shapefile - you can then organize your field names, etc. if needed

Hope that helps!

meryloo

Comment: thx. Tabulate Area did it!